# auto_open Macro produces error code 91

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

The macro is an auto_open() that executes upon opening the spreadsheet. It checks first to see if the year has changed since it was last used. If it has, it changes it to the current year. The sheet that is the focus is named "Time". It has a list of all days in the year as well as holidays. The principal function is to search for the current day according to the system date. When found, it points to the current day for the purpose of recording hours worked for that day.

In Excel 2016 it functions as expected. In Excel 2010 it bombs with error 91.

Thanks for all who have looked at this question previously. First time in stack overflow. Don't you hate newbies? LOL

```
Public Sub Auto_Open()
Dim Today As Date
Dim Jan1 As Date
Dim Curday As Date
Dim DefYear As Long
Dim CurYear As Long
Dim JDate As Long
Dim TimeSheet As Object

Set TimeSheet = Sheets("Time")

    Today = DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), Day(Now()))
    TimeSheet.Select
    Range("A371").Select
    CurYear = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Curday = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
    If Today > Curday Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Year(Now)
    End If
    Range("A1").Select
    Jan1 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
    Curday = Today
    Cells.Find(What:=Curday, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    JDate = DateDiff("d", Jan1, Today)
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to change `Dim TimeSheet As Object` to `Dim TimeSheet As Worksheet`. Also, change the `.Activate` at the end of the find to `.Select`. Finally, I am not quite sure if you can immediately `.Select` or `Activate` the result of a `.Find`. You may have to store if in a variable first.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is time to graduate from relying on the [Range .Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197597.aspx) and 
[Range .Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681.aspx) methods in favor of explicit range / cell / worksheet references.

```
'Public Sub Auto_Open()
'workbook and worksheet subs are Private, not Public!
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Dim Today As Date
    Dim Jan1 As Date
    Dim strDate As String, curDay As Date, curYear As Long
    'dim defYear As Long
    Dim JDate As Long
    'Dim TimeSheet As Object
    Dim fndDate As Range


    'Today = DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), Day(Now()))
    'this can be simpler as Today = Date or Today = Int(Now)
    'or just use Date anytime you would use Today and discard the Today var altogether

    'Set TimeSheet = Sheets("Time")
    'TimeSheet.Select
    'this is better as an explicit worksheet parent reference
    With Worksheets("Time")
        .Activate   '<~~ activate the worksheet for display purposes but do not rely on the ActiveSheet reference

        'Range("A371").Select
        'curYear = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        'curDay = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
        'we are working with a defined parent worksheet
        'there are only three uses of ActiveCell but I'll puit them in a With End With anyways
        With .Range("A371")
            curYear = .Offset(0, 1).Value2
            curDay = .Value2    '<~~ don't know what this does since it is reassigned a little further down

            'If Today > curDay Then
            'Date is fine for this
            If Date > curDay Then
                .Offset(0, 1) = Year(Date)
            End If
        End With


        'Range("A1").Select
        'work with A1 (actually A2 with the offset)
        Jan1 = .Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Value

        'curDay = Today
        'this seems like a unnecessary use of two vars - just use Date
        curDay = Date

        Set fndDate = .Cells.Find(What:=CDate(Date), After:=.Cells(1, 1), MatchCase:=False, _
                                  LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchFormat:=False, _
                                  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        'date formatting can foul up a .Find operation. If the above failed, try again with a CDate conversion on string date using the "Short Date" format
        If fndDate Is Nothing Then
            strDate = Format(Date, "Short Date")
            Set fndDate = .Cells.Find(What:=CDate(strDate), After:=.Cells(1, 1), MatchCase:=False, _
                                      LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchFormat:=False, _
                                      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        End If

        If Not fndDate Is Nothing Then
            fndDate.Offset(0, 1).Select '<~~ selected for user interface assistance only
        Else
            Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        End If

        'JDate = DateDiff("d", Jan1, Today)
        'again, Date is the current date, Now is the current date and time and Time is the current time
        'DateDif is unnecessary since the difference in days is simple subtraction
        JDate = Date - Jan1
        'don't know what you want to do with jdate
        Debug.Print JDate
    End With
End Sub
```

Your code is working so I've performed a rewrite with attention on getting rid of any implicit references that rely on the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx) or [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx). Additionally, there are three date-type reserved vars in VBA. **Date** is the current date, Now is the current date with current time and Time is the current time without the date.